# GlobalFilter vs WebFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm taking the first step in Spring Cloud Gateway.
During the study, I wanted to understand better the use of `GlobalFilter`. In the specific, I intend to have some filter applied every time for **every** route.

Reading the documentation ([reference](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#global-filters)) there are two ways for reaching my goal.
The first is the use of `GlobalFilter` and the second is to have a `GatewayFilter` in `default-filters`.

Both the solutions work pretty well, **but** only for the routes defined in the YAML configuration.
If I have any RouteLocator or RouterFunctions I need to declare the filter every time

```
.filters(f -> f.globalFilter("something"))
```

The only way that I have found for reaching my goal is to use directly a `WebFilter` ([reference](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-filters))

So my question here is if anybody can explain the difference between the two filters `GatewayFilter`/`GlobalFilter` and `Webfilter`

Maybe the answer is in the Spring documentation, but I can not find it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#global-filters here is the docs for global filters.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasAndolf , but I had already found that documentation (I have reported it in the question description) But reading that documentation, and the `WebFilter` one I do not find a useful description on why I should use one instead of other.

Comment: @AndreaPosadino I need the same clarification. We have defined a explicit rest controller in gateway and others are routes back to downstream services. We have specific gateway filters for all routes. But for the rest controllers, these filters are not applied somehow.  WebFilter is the only way to go ahead. But WebFilter applies to both rest controllers and all other routes methods as well. How can we prevent this? Any suggestions

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have a filter for every single route (for routes defined in the YAML as well as controllers / endpoints hosted in your gateway itself), `WebFilter` should be the way to go.

If you want a filter for all the routes, but not for the endpoints hosted in your gateway, then you can go for Default Filters / Global Filters.

And lastly, you have GatewayFilters that can be configured for specific routes.

I noticed in the source code that the routes go via `FilteringWebHandler` and the endpoints within the gateway are mapped directly to the controller methods and they don't really go via these handlers (they go via normal WebFilters though). Hence, the above.